# Fill null values with previous value in same column

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
Date            Name    Country  Channel    Joined_version    Expected_version
25/07/2018  Product 1   A            ios     1                1
25/07/2018  Product 1   B            ios     null             1
25/07/2018  Product 1   C            ios     null             1
25/07/2018  Product 1   D            play    2                2
25/07/2018  Product 2   A            play    1.1              1.1

26/07/2018  Product 2   A            ios     null             1.1
26/07/2018  Product 2   B            ios     null             1.1
26/07/2018  Product 2   C            ios     null             1.1
26/07/2018  Product 2   D            ios     null             1.1

26/07/2018  Product 1   E            ios     3                3

26/07/2018  Product 2   A            play    null             1.1

27/07/2018  Product 1   A            ios     null             3
27/07/2018  Product 1   B            ios     null             3
27/07/2018  Product 1   C            ios     null             3
```

In the above table, I have joined version from another table which has date and version. (Ex: On 26th a new version for Product 1 for ios was launched )

So only the specific dates will have the version number. The remaining cells will be Null.

I want to fill the null values with the previous version name which i will use to aggregate other fields.

The version depends on date, channel and product and **does not** depend on country.

I tried the below query (from stackoverflow) and various permutations of the same.

```
    SELECT 
    t.*,
    FIRST_VALUE(joined_version) OVER (PARTITION BY val_part ORDER BY DATE, name, 
    channel) AS expected_version
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
    a.*,
    COUNT(joined_version) OVER (ORDER BY DATE order by date, name, channel) 
    AS val_part
    FROM table AS t ORDER BY date ASC
    )
```

My output has a lot of missing values (for expected_version) and the more the products, more the missing values.

Please point me in the right direction and I will also provide any more details if required!

Comment: What's your using SQL Language?Mysql or postgresql?

Comment: Postgres. I’ll remove the other tag.

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged mysql and postgres both.

In mysql, you can use session variables for this:

```
SELECT Date, Name, Channel, 
    CASE WHEN Joined_version IS NULL THEN
        @prev
    ELSE
        @prev := Joined_version
    END  AS Expected_version
FROM t1
order by Date, Name, Channel
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as:

```
select t.*,
       coalese(joined_version,
               first_value(joined_version) over (partition by name order by (joined_version is not null)::int desc, date desc, name, channel)
              )
from t;
```

You might need to check if the `name` and `channel` are handled the way you want them to.

This basically implements `lag(ignore nulls)`, which Postgres does not support.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/13179) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Tired this, but its not working. I am still missing a lot of values! If I understand right, this  will replace the top part of the query I posted ?

Comment: @0Ajax0 . . . There was a small logic error (`is null` instead of `is not null`).  It should be working now.